# 2 series on my chart

Tags: asp.net-4.0, charts

I would like to show 2 series on the same chart, however I'm not sure how to update the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UcSalesSeries.ascx.cs" Inherits="Silverlight.ConfigEnhanced.Web.UcSalesSeries" %>
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
    Height="500px" Width="750px" >
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" XValueMember="EndOfMonth" 
            YValueMembers="Quantity" >
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series2" XValueMember="EndOfMonth" 
            YValueMembers="Quantity" >
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas> <Legends>
                <asp:Legend TableStyle="Auto" Docking="Top" >
                </asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Data.DataClasses1DataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (EndOfMonth, Quantity)" 
    TableName="T_SalesDatas" OrderBy="EndOfMonth" Where="Model == @Model">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="XXS" Name="Model" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

the second serie I would like to see is the same as above, but I would be changing the parameter

```
  <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="NEWVALUE" Name="Model" Type="String" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chart does not support multiple DataSources so you will need to manually add the points from code behind to the chart when rendering the page. You create two tables from your data with the different parameters and iterate each table and adding them to the chart manually.

Read more in the section *'Manual' series population* on this MSDN blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx